# How HTML5 page structure affects W3C validation and SEO

Tags: html, seo, w3c-validation, google-crawlers

If we declare page as HTML5, Is it mandatory to follow HTML5 page structure ? . 
Below are two examples shows the ideal HTML5 page and page which is not following HTML5 structure.

But when i validated these two pages using w3c validator, these pages successfully checked as HTML5 without errors.

ex:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Your menu</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
The content of the document......

<footer>
        <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

My page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>Your menu</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
    The content of the document......

<div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright 2009 Your name</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

1. If we specify doctype as html5 do we need to make website html5
   specific / do we have  to maintain html5 structure ?
2. Is it a good idea to validate againist HTML5 when we built website
   in HTML4
3. When we specify html5 why so many errors got reduced?
4. Upto what extent the page should be validated?
5. How does html5 page affects the SEO

Comment: HTML5 ist not exactly a new specification of the Hypertext Markup Language, it's a set of tools and techniques (including JavaScript and CSS). Just because there are new tags, it doesn't mean it's mandatory to use them. From a SEO perspective, it is probably recommended to use them because they make the page structure more readable to search angines and makes it easier for them to determine the relevant content. The navigation (`<nav>`), the footer (`<footer>`) or the sidebar (`<aside>`) are probably not as relevant as the rest of the content.

Comment: The w3c validator is not the be all and end all. Just write good semantic html.

Comment: I have around 500 html pages which are not html5, and neither they use html5 tags(nav, header, article, footer ..) means they dont follow html5 page structure. Its very difficult to convert all the pages to follow the HTML5 page structure. And to reduce the validation errors in w3c I have to just put the <!Doctype html>. So My doubt : will that helps in SEO or Do i need to make all pages to follow HTML5 page structure.

Comment: @Vinay Talking about SEO, a (mostly) valid markup is maybe one little part of it. I wouldn't pay too much attention to what the validator says as long as you know what you're doing. Even google.com does not validate correctly. Semantics is what really matters. The better you can describe your content semantically, the easier it is for e.g. google to determine what's relevant and what's not. For instance: `<div id="header">` - Google doesn't care about the id, it's still just another div. But `<header>` says: Hey, I'm not just another structure element, I am the header of the page/article.

Comment: @Quasdunk I agree with most of what you say - The OP's page giving 300 errors or 76 errors, depending on which DOCTYPE his docs have is proof that the validator isn't absolutely trustworthy. But I say it helps! For one thing, documents that are error-free certainly have a bigger chance of being displayed the same in different browsers. And I'm quite sure that errors like, e.g., link elements in the wrong places can affect your SEO results.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes. But: those `<header>`, `<nav>` etc elements are not mandatory! A HTML5 document is a valid HTML5 document even if they are "missing".
2. No.
3. I beg your pardon?
4. Can you give an example? If you mean proprietary style properties like `-webkit-appearance`, yes, you'll have to live with the fact that those don't validate.
5. I'm not sure they do, actually. They may have an effect in the future though.

Comment: I have around 500 html pages which are not html5, and neither they use html5 tags(nav, header, article, footer ..) means they dont follow html5 page structure. Its very difficult to convert all the pages to follow the HTML5 page structure. And to reduce the validation errors in w3c I have to just put the <!Doctype html>. So My doubt : will that helps in SEO or Do i need to make all pages to follow HTML5 page structure.

Comment: If your 500 pages are all valid HTML4, just leave them as is; HTML4 is not going to go away or anything. But if your pages are not valid HTML anyway, who cares what DOCTYPE they have. Anyway, can you give an example of something that gives a validation error for HTML4, but is fine for HTML5?

Comment: You can viwe the source code here:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3uU23D89jnGeWxiak51ZmlUYlk/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3uU23D89jnGSzhjWVdGWXV5cms/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hm. That document has a lot of structural errors, like the `<link>` elements in the body and things like that. And apparently, those confuse the HTML5 checker in a different way than they do the HTML4 checker, resulting in fewer errors. Apart from the occasional `<div>` inside an `<a>`, I myself don't really see that many more errors against the HTML4 standard than against the HTML5 standard.

Comment: But when i checked against HTML5, The errors were reduced to 76 , while it was around 300 in HTML4.