# How exactly declaring page doctype as HTML5 reduces the error in W3C markup validation

Tags: html, doctype, w3c-validation

I have a website which has got around 1000 pages. I declared all html doctype to use XHTML 1.0 strict

I checked the website pages using W3C markup validation tool,  I got 320 errors, Then I changed the doctype to HTML 4.0 the errors reduced to 300.

Then I used the HTML5 doctype, Then errors got reduced to 75. So How these errors got reduced by just changing the doctype.

**EDIT**

My Question is:

1) Validating my pages against XHTML1.0  standards gives me more than 300 errors, Which is quite huge and bit difficult to resolve them.

2) Validating my pages against HTML5 standards gives me around 70 errors, Which is not a issue and can resolve them easily.

So In this case which HTML version i have to use so that It does not affects SEO of the pages, Because w3c validation also affects the SEO

If i just use HTML5 doctype but not exactly the page structure (nav, header, section, footer, article ....), Will this really matters Because I have got around 1000 pages which is very difficult make them to follow the HTML5 page structure.

**What i am thinking is to reduce the errors in w3c, I will just change the doctype to HTML5 and resolve the w3c errors. Is this a good idea. Or If any please suggest me.**

Comment: Your edits have seriously changed the nature of your question so it is now a  duplicate of your own, previously closed, question: [How HTML5 page structure affects W3C validation and SEO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587711/how-html5-page-structure-affects-w3c-validation-and-seo)

Comment: so, I did not get the proper solution for the post, So here is the one

Answer (score 3):

As @Quentin says, there are many differences between XHTML 1.0 Strict and HTML5. Apart from the new tags, there are other significative differences, some examples:

> 1 - All XHTML tags and attributes should be written in lower case.

- Is there any uppercase tags or attributes in your code?

> 2 - In XHTML, when you use a singleton tag like `<br/>` you are
>   required to  include a trailing slash in the element for valid XHTML.
>   In HTML 5,  the trailing slash is optional.

- Have you self-closing the singleton tags?

> 3 - All XHTML attribute values must be quoted. In HTML5, you don’t
>   need to place quotation marks around attribute values if there are no
>   spaces.

- Are your attribute values properly quoted?

> 4 - All the XHTML tags must be nested properly.

- Is this your case?

> 5 - The HTML5 `<meta>` tag with the charset attribute is simpler than in
>   XHTML: `<meta charset=utf-8>`

- If you're using this tag your document fails in XHTML

> 6 - There’s also no need to include the Type Attribute for Style Sheet
>   Links and Scripts.

- If you didn't declare this attribute, your document fails in XHTML

These are a few examples of how different can validation will be simply changing the Doctype. You could check these points to see if is there any your case.

You can retrieve all the info here: [Baby steps from XHTML to HTML5](http://www.crimsondesigns.com/blog/2012/03/baby-steps-from-xhtml-to-html5/)

**I will just change the doctype to HTML5 and resolve the w3c errors. Is this a good idea?**

Well, HTML5 is more "easier" to construct, because is more flexible, but is a decision you must decide *before* start making the website. I suggest you to read the [W3C specifications for XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/) and [HTML5 specifications](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/), and then decide what language fits better with your requirements and how code it to have a valid markup.

Answer (score 2):

Because, quite simply, different versions of HTML are different and allow different things.

`<video>` for example is new in HTML 5 so will error in HTML 4.

Comment: I am not using any HTML5 tags, You can view the code here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3uU23D89jnGSzhjWVdGWXV5cms/edit

Comment: I said "for example" there are plenty of other differences.

Comment: Do you think the following statement is also a resaon

"The W3 validator link works in "Doctype: -//W3C//DTD HTML+RDFa 1.1//EN". You have to re-validate it in HTML5 Doctype and you will get less errors. Since HTML5 is not finalized nobody knows what will be added, changed or removed. So making it validate wont do that big of a difference. Dont forget that valid sites might still display messed up on internet explorer."

source: https://drupal.org/node/1480360

Comment: Errr. No. If using different Doctypes give different results, then that is because the document conforms more closely to one then the other. Making it validator will make a difference, it finds a lot of errors that have a practical impact (and the fact HTML 5 is still subject to change doesn't really matter, the majority of it is very stable now). Any browser might display valid markup incorrectly - they all have bugs. Validation is easy QA that deals with quite a lot of problems. It doesn't deal with all problems and doesn't replace testing in browsers.

Comment: please see my EDIT in the post

Answer (score 2):

Poor code is poor code, regardless of doctype. You will see fewer errors when validating with an html5 doctype because html5 as a spec is much less rigid in how it defines html to be structured.

[Google doesn't validate pages.](http://www.glendaledesigns.com/matt-cutts-w3c-validation-not-a-ranking-factor-in-google/) That said, better markup can help a search engine to better understand your website. Although if you're just changing the doctype and not cleaning up the poor code, it's not going to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because xhtml uses xml parser, which demands more strict syntax. I've found it out that `<!DOCTYPE html>` is much more tolerant, for using standard that is still in developent (last subsentence is more my guess than concrete).